# mrpt The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3

Tags: eigen

trying to compile mrpt 1.3.2 under Windows and MinGW32.

The CMake configuration has the EIGEN_USE_EMBEDDED_VERSION checked, and my make command is [mingw32-make -f makefile CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11" SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release]

The build explodes compiling bayes/CParticleFilter.cpp, and yields the error message "The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3. All that functionality has moved to Eigen/Core."

What am I doing wrong (besides building under Windows ;) )?

Answer (score 0):

It is already fixed in the `master` branch of MRPT in GitHub, please give it a try or wait for the next stable release.